# Selecting column name from other database table through function in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

Here i need to select a column name by using function(stored procedure) which is present in other database table using PostgreSQL.

I have sql server query as shown below.

Example:

```
create procedure sp_testing 
as 
       if not exists ( select ssn from testdb..testtable) /*ssn is the column-name of testtable which exists in testdb database */
       ...
```

Q: Can i do the same in PostgreSQL?

Comment: Maybe [dblink](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/dblink.html) can help?

Comment: Postgres is different than SQL Server. You might want to think about moving different databases from SQL Server into different schemas in Postgres. Rather than trying to "copy" a setup from one DBMS to another you should think about how the underlying requirement of that setup is best reflected in the new environment (and read the manual before starting to code)

Comment: @TomasGreif: dblink has been superseded by fdw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is not very clear, but if you want to know if a column by a certain name exists in a table by a certain name in a remote PostgreSQL database, then you should first set up a [foreign data wrapper](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/postgres-fdw.html), which is a multi-stage process. Then to test the existence of a certain column in a table you need to formulate a query that conforms to the standards of the particular DBMS that you are connecting to. Use the remote `information_schema.tables` table for optimal compatibility (which is here specified as `remote_tables` which you must have defined with a prior `CREATE FOREIGN TABLE` command):

```
CREATE FUNCTION sp_testing () AS $$
BEGIN
  PERFORM *
  FROM remote_tables
  WHERE table_name = 'testtable'
  AND column_name = 'ssn';

  IF NOT FOUND THEN
     ...
  END IF;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

If you want to connect to another type of DBMS, you need to write some custom function in f.i. C or perl and then call that from within a PostgreSQL function on your local machine. The test on the column is then best done inside the function which should therefore take connection parameters, table name and column name as parameters, and return a boolean to inform the result.

Before you start testing this, **make sure that you read all the documentation** on connecting to remote servers and learning **[PL/pgSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql.html)** first would also be a nice gesture to demonstrate your own efforts before you ask for help.

Comment: One more question to you please: Where can i see that foreign wrapper table/server located? Thanks

Comment: I don't understand your question. The documentation is accessible online; see the hyperlink in my answer. Once defined, a foreign server or fdw itself is not "visible" like other objects but the foreign tables (really just local placeholders for the foreign relation) can be seen just like other relations.

Comment: Okay fine. Sorry for such type of question.