# Retrieve tables name from several databases in Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

I have two databases `new_site,old_site` I'm connecting to the database server via Postgres user and have full permission and I connect to new_site db.

I need to get tables names for old_site so I tried this:

```
SELECT table_name 
FROM information_schema.tables 
WHERE table_catalog = $$old_site$$;
```

but I get a `null` as result.

If I run this query:

```
SELECT table_name 
FROM information_schema.tables 
WHERE table_catalog = current_database();
```

I get back the table name and it works.

I expect the output is table name of old_site db, how can I do this?

I was also reading some solutions here like:
[Selecting column name from other database table through function in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23672134/selecting-column-name-from-other-database-table-through-function-in-postgresql)

But it's not like my case.

Comment: You can't query other databases in Postgres directly. Only through e.g. a foreign data wrapper or the dblink module.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, what do you mean ? can you explain please